# Redirecting URL assigned to Home Tab on Plone

Tags: authentication, plone

On Plone, I am looking at establishing a User Group with an initial login page (collective.onlogin) that leads to what I hope will be the new Home Page. How do I change the Home Tab to reflect this once the authorised user has moved past the LogIn page. Currently, the home tab reflects and returns to the login page - string${globals_view/navigationRootUrl}

Answer (score 1):

Where `string:${globals_view/navigationRootUrl}` is specified you may specify other expressions. In this case, you'll probably wish to create a BrowserView or Python Script that returns the path you want, since it sounds like there may be some real logic. Then, call that view or script rather than `globals_view/navigationRootUrl`.

Comment: Steve - Programming is beyond my skill set at this point. I've had a look at quintagroup.plonetabs but it doesn't want to play with 4.3.1 - Thanks for taking the time to reply

Answer (score 0):

Found that if I de-activated collective.onlogin, went to the "Change content item as default view ..." and selected the home page that I wanted, then reactivated collective.onlogin I would get what I wanted. The login page is still very vanilla, but that can wait for another day. Hope this helps the next person.